# Changing Android API Key for GCM

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I have inherited a GCM application to send messages to android phones.  We have an Android API Key set up that may have been compromised.  I would just like to ensure that I change it in a way that doesn't break the apps that are currently running.

I think what I do is:

> 1. Create a new Android API Key here:  https://console.developers.google.com/project/my-project-name/apiui/credential
> 2. Delete the existing Android API Key

As I understand it from the docs, when I create my new API Key from the last apk generated, the SHA1 I used to generate it, along with the package name, should match up to my already-deployed android apps.  I should not need to re-upload an apk.

Is that correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and no.

YES, if you are using OAuth 2.0, which depends only on the SHA1 and package name;

NO, if you are using API key, which usually require you to place your key in your  manifest file.

Comment: Thanks.  So, totally noob question, but how can I tell which one this is using?  I don't see an api key in the manifest, but is there any other way to know?

Comment: Or in the java file. if you were following the (getting started guild](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start?configured), your key would be in `GcmSender.java`